# Libmemcached make error

Tags: php, debian, hiphop, libmemcached

I am having a problem with the make command for libmemcached, it throws up all these errors near the end of the command

```
CXX    example/memcached_light.o
example/memcached_light.cc:40:19: error: event.h: No such file or directory
  CXX    example/storage.o
  CXX    util/daemon.o
example/memcached_light.cc:62: error: field 'event' has incomplete type
example/memcached_light.cc: In function 'void drive_client(memcached_socket_t, short int, void*)':
example/memcached_light.cc:130: error: 'EV_WRITE' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:135: error: 'EV_READ' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:138: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:138: error: 'event_set' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:139: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:139: error: 'event_base_set' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:141: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:141: error: 'event_add' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc: In function 'void accept_handler(memcached_socket_t, short int, void*)':
example/memcached_light.cc:187: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:187: error: 'EV_READ' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:187: error: 'event_set' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:188: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:188: error: 'event_base_set' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:189: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:189: error: 'event_add' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
example/memcached_light.cc:596: error: 'event_init' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:608: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:608: error: 'EV_READ' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:608: error: 'EV_PERSIST' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:608: error: 'event_set' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:610: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:610: error: 'event_base_set' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:611: error: 'struct connection' has no member named 'event'
example/memcached_light.cc:611: error: 'event_add' was not declared in this scope
example/memcached_light.cc:629: error: 'event_base_loop' was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [example/memcached_light.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/hiphop/libmemcached-1.0.13'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm trying to install phphiphop on debian squeeze 64bit as per [these](http://web-site-creation.org/agence/article28/installer-php-hiphop-debian-squeeze) instructions I found. I'm using a newer version than the instructions but the same happens with the old version aswell, and phphiphop says it supports 0.39+. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like libevent and its `event.h` isn't available on the machine. Try

```
apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, libevent-dev installed correctly but libevent cannot be found

 
 
    E: Unable to locate package libevent

Comment: no problem, it seems to be working, still installing but no errors yet. Although I think you left libevent there as a clever ruse to trick me, well played sir! Thanks again.